# PhpStorm does not recognize PHP

Tags: php, phpstorm

I saw many different questions here, but nothing was helpful to me.
I have no trouble with an interpreter, I tried to reset PhpStorm's cache.

It looks like file `functions.php` isn't accessible.

[image]

I really don't want to make a total reset. Maybe somebody has an idea how to solve it?

Comment: Are you sure that path to php interpreter is set in IDE?

Comment: What do the tooltips say when you hover over those yellow parts?

Comment: @Jeto nothing shown

Comment: If you go to `File | Settings | Editor | File Types`, can you make sure that the `*.php` extension is present in the `PHP` section?

Comment: @Jeto this is fine because my file visually looks like PHP, but not as plain text.

Comment: @zhartaunik I assume you have just updated to 2020.2 version? How did you install it -- built-in patch or separate standalone installer? Please uninstall current version (keep all the settings) and install it again into an empty folder.

Comment: This could be that PhpStorm is unable to properly read bundled stub files ... https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360000521544-PHP-built-in-functions-classes-etc-are-not-recognized?page=2

Comment: This is exactly the same as I had. I updated PHPStorm to 2020.2 by removing the previous version and extracting an archive in the same folder.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what I actually did and how to reproduce this issue again, but now it works well. I took previous version of PHPstorm. When I installed new one, the previous one was simply renamed to sth like 'phpstorm2'.

Here are my thoughts what actually happened:

As I understand for highlighting is responsible that part of application which is managed under `Languages & Frameworks / PHP / PHP Runtime`.

To reproduce this issue you may try to disable there "Core / Core" and try to write down in any place of your phpfile following:

```
\Exception::class();
```

And in your case this class will not be highlighted, as it presents in `Core_c.php`. In my case it is placed in

> /opt/phpstorm/plugins/php/lib/php.jar!/stubs/Core/Core_c.php

[image: Phpstorm Core_c.php]

I'm 100% sure that these libs were always enabled, but why I didn't saw this - that is the question.

**So if I face this issue again my steps would be:**

1. Try to verify `Languages & Frameworks / PHP / PHP Runtime`. The better way would be to enable ALL libs.
2. Check External Libraries in the project tree. Check read privileges for `/opt/phpstorm/plugins/php/lib/php.jar` and probably reinstall this plugin.
3. Try to find out function which I don't actually see in External Libraries.

Comment: Sorry, so if you disable Core/Core - you will get correct built-in functions resolve in your code?